# Error sending POST request to rest api server using boost.asio

Tags: javascript, c++, rest, http, boost-asio

I'm trying to use `boost.asio` (and possibly `boost.beast`) to send a `POST` request containing JSON data to a rest api written in javascript. When I use `Postman` the api handles the `POST` request and saves it to a mysql database successfully, but when I try to send it using my `c++` code the server crashes and return `Exception: read_until: End of file` on c++ side and `Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1`
 on the server side. Here is my c++ code I'm using to send the request...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "main -start" << endl;
    try
    {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    string ipAddress = argv[1]; //"localhost" for loop back or ip address otherwise, i.e.- www.boost.org;       
    string portNum = argv[2]; //"8000" for instance;
    string hostAddress;
    if (portNum.compare("80") != 0) // add the ":" only if the port number is not 80 (proprietary port number).
    {
         hostAddress = ipAddress + ":" + portNum;
    }
    else 
    { 
        hostAddress = ipAddress;
    }
    string wordToQuery = "";//this will be used for entry indexing
    string queryStr = argv[3]; //"/api/v1/similar?word=" + wordToQuery;
    string json = argv[4]; //json text

    // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(ipAddress, portNum);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

    boost::asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << "POST " << queryStr << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";  // note that you can change it if you wish to HTTP/1.0
    request_stream << "Host: " << hostAddress << "\r\n";
    request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0";
    request_stream << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream << "Content-Length: " << json.length() << "\r\n"; 
    request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    request_stream << json;

    // Send the request.
    boost::asio::write(socket, request);

    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (status_code != 200)
    {
        std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

    // Process the response headers.
    std::string header;
    while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
    {
        std::cout << header << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    // Write whatever content we already have to output.
    if (response.size() > 0)
    {
        std::cout << &response;
    }

    // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
    boost::system::error_code error;
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, response,boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
    {
          std::cout << &response;
    }

    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
          throw boost::system::system_error(error);
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}

return 0;
```

}

Below is the part of the server code that is suppose to handle the post request and save it to mysql

```
app.post('/licence', function (req, res) {
collectRequestData(req, result => {
  console.log(result);
  sleep(5000);
  connection.query('INSERT INTO licence SET ?',result, function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) throw error;
res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});
});

function collectRequestData(request, callback) {
const FORM_URLENCODED = 'application/json';
if(request.headers['content-type'] === FORM_URLENCODED) {
    let body = '';
    request.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    request.on('end', () => {
        callback(JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
else {
    callback(null);
}
```

}

I'm compiling with `g++ -I boost file.cpp -o test.o -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_regex -lpthread` which works fine and then, when I run `./test.o host port route JSON_text`, I get the error. My JSON_text looks like this `'{"hash": "test data 1","size": 123,"difficulty": -1,"timestamp": null,"date": null}'`. If anyone has any insight to what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated. I am using ubuntu 18.04 and nodejs for the server.

Comment: It's a guess but maybe you aren't escaping your JSON correctly on the command line

Comment: I believe you don't have to use `res.end` twice. Can you try removing one in your post.

Comment: Do you ever check the server's logs? Getting a 500 means there is an error on the server side and i'm pretty sure there is a big red message somewhere waiting to be read.

Comment: @sjahan the error reads "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of null"

Comment: @john I'm not sure what you mean by escaping JSON, could you explain.

Comment: @eduPeeth yes i did not mean to put the second res.end in.

Comment: @JackTroetschel Your JSON data contains space and quotes. Those have special meaning on the command line. Assuming you are on Linux or Unix you should enclose the JSON data in single quotes.

Comment: @JackTroetschel `result.fname` <-- `result` is null and you try to access something on it, that's your problem.

Comment: @john can't believe I didn't realize that but yes that fixed that problem but now I have a different error, shown in edit

Comment: @sjahan that did fix the fname error but my request still isn't working, you can now see new error in edit

Comment: @JackTroetschel `console.log(result);` what value do you see for `result`?

Comment: @john it prints null when it's suppose to print the JSON test I sent it

Comment: @JackTroetschel Well that would indicate `if(request.headers['content-type'] === FORM_URLENCODED) {` is false, no? And in fact looking at the C++ code that seems to be the case.

Comment: @john I tried changing `'content-type'` to `'Content-Type'` and it's still printing null, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @JackTroetschel I don't think the case is the problem. In you C++ code you have content type equals "application/json; charset=utf-8 " and in your server code you have "application/json". They're just different. At least that's what I think. Why don't you add `console.log(request.headers['content-type']);` to your code to find out exactly what you have.